# Como sumar resultados de un GROUP BY MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estoy intentado sumar resultados de un GROUP BY de MySQL pero no he logrado hacerlo, éste es mi código:

```
SELECT country,SUM(visits) AS visits,SUM(visits-1) AS repetidos, COUNT(1) AS total FROM stats GROUP BY country HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Adjunto imagen de mi resultado de mi código y lo que quisiera lograr con el:

[image: Resultado deseado]

También dejare captura de mis tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la posible ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente ya esta sumando lo que pasa que estas agrupando por country.

Si quieres que sea la suma de todos serian de la siguiente forma:

```sql
SELECT SUM(visits) AS visits,SUM(visits-1) AS repetidos, COUNT(1) AS total FROM stats HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Por otro lado si quieres un nuevo row que contenga un resumen total entonces podrias hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```sql
SELECT country,SUM(visits) AS visits,SUM(visits-1) AS repetidos, COUNT(1) AS total FROM stats GROUP BY country HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
UNION
SELECT 'Total' as country, SUM(visits) AS visits,SUM(visits-1) AS repetidos, COUNT(1) AS total FROM stats s1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM stats s2 where s2.country = s1.country LIMIT 1,1 ) ;
```

Nota: el codigo con la linea

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM stats s2 where s2.country = s1.country LIMIT 1,1 ) ;
```

Se utiliza para filtrar valores repetidos.